# Flutter file.readFileAsLines() and file.readFileAsLinesSync() both return empty List<String>

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I'm pretty new with dart and flutter and now after trying different thing I'm out of ideas.
Basically I'm writing an application in which you upload a txt file, it make some changes and then let you save the file. All works fine except the fact that I have to click two times the button to generate the modified file because the first time the function does not read the file content or something like that.
This is the function:

```
List<String> readGcode(File  file) {
  List<String> lines = file.readAsLinesSync();
  return lines;
}
```

Basically I pass the already created file to the function and this should read the content and return it as an array of strings. the thing I do not understand is why both with sync and async functions the first time it return an empty array and the second time it returns correctly.

Also another example: if I upload file1.txt and click the button the function return nothing, but then instead of reclicking the button if I change the file and upload file2.txt without restarting the application when I click the generate file button the function returns the content of file1.txt.
It's like an issue with the main function not waiting to have the data from the file but as I said this thing happens both with sync and async function (result is the same also if I use the await command or not).

Also I put the file.readAsLines(); in a dedicated function just to make some testa otherwise I would put it in the main function.

Comment: You probably need to add more code. Especially the part where your `File` is created/opened and passed to the function.

Comment: File alteredGcodeFile =  File(await tempDirectory());

This is the code that creates the file.
But to be honest I miss the open file part. I'm learning from online tutorials the one I followed to use the files didn't properly opened the after creating it.
I just went right into reading and writing things in it.
Am I supposed to create the file and then open it like with java?

Comment: The file does not have to be opened. You can do something like `File myFile = File(<path to file>)` and check that it exists using `myFile.existsSync()` and that it contains data by `myFile.length()`.